# Postgres function: assiging results from built-in function to variable

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to assign results of REPLACE() built-in Postgres function to another variable?
I am trying something like this, but it does not work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION uri2text(uri text) RETURNS text AS $$
SET temp_text = SELECT REPLACE(uri , '%20', ' ');
RETURN temp_text;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have variables in SQL (which is the language that `language sql` selects for the function). To use variables, you need PL/pgSQL, and [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) assignment is done using `:=` (or `=`) in PL/pgSQL. And you need to declare a variable before you can use it.

You also don't need a `SELECT` statement to call a function.

So if you do want to use PL/pgSQL, the function needs to look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION uri2text(uri text) 
  RETURNS text 
AS $$
declare
  temp_text text;
begin
  temp_text := REPLACE(uri , '%20', ' ');
  RETURN temp_text;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However you wouldn't even need a variable:

```
CREATE FUNCTION uri2text(uri text) 
  RETURNS text 
AS $$
begin
  RETURN REPLACE(uri , '%20', ' ');
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And you don't even need PL/pgSQL for this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION uri2text(uri text) 
  RETURNS text 
AS $$
 SELECT REPLACE(uri , '%20', ' ');
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Note that in case of the SQL function, you do need the SELECT because in SQL there is no `return` or assignment.